# de inicio en la infancia -- en inicio de la infancia .. which is more correct or what is the difference between them

Tags: traducción

Which is more correct or what is the difference between them?

The first translates as **childhood-onset** and the latter as **in the early childhood**

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to express. "onset" means the beginning of a disease or "something unpleasant", so it can be prepended with whatever word you want that express epochs or events ("*childhood-onset, early-onset, sudden-onset*").

*Childhood*, by itself, means "infancia"

- "*de inicio en la infancia*", if your sentence relates to a disease or something similar, then it is "**childhood-onset**", for example "childhood-onset diabetes", or "childhood-onset schizophrenia". That disease is "*[una enfermedad] de inicio en la infancia*" or better yet "**que se origina en la infancia**"

on the other hand:

- "*en inicio de la infancia*", it sounds better like this: "al inicio de la infancia". It's not scoped to diseases anymore, and express whatever you want, if it happens in the childhood: "kids start kindergarten *al inicio de la infancia*", "teething begins *al inicio de la infancia*"

Answer (score 0):

For me both "de inicio en la infancia" and "en inicio de la infancia" seem a little bit artificious.

As jonayreyes said, if you're trying to mean that something unpleasant begins "**que se origina en la infancia**" or "**cuyo inicio se da en la infancia**" sound more natural.

On the other hand, I'd translate "in the early childhood" as "**en la más tierna infancia**" if you're in a very formal or lyric context. Otherwise you could also translate it as "**en la etapa infantil**" or "**cuando aún se es muy pequeño**" in a more common context.

I'm sure we could help you out much better if you give us a little bit more context!

Cheers!

Ivan